# Get a pointer to an object in a std::set (c++)

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, set

I have a std set S.  S contains a few instances of MyType.  **Is this the best way to get a pointer to an instance of MyType in S?**

```
MyType *pointerToMyType = (MyType*)(&*S.find(anotherInstanceOfMyType));
```

The above code works.  I'm just not sure if it's the best or safest way.

**Edit**:  I do check the result of find to S.end() before the above line.

**Edit**:  Removing the cast causes the following compile-time error: "Invalid conversion from 'const MyType*' to 'MyType*'"

Comment: You can't legitimately get a `MyType*` because the objects stored in a `std::set` are immutable.

Comment: @James McNellis: Indeed. None of the other answers noticed this.

Comment: @Tomalak: I think everybody knows what is meant when someone says STL set.

Comment: @Billy: Were that the case, I would not have had to ask the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should *not* take a mutable reference or pointer to an element in a `set`. If you change it's properties, then you will invalidate the container's invariants, causing Undefined Behaviour. That compile-time error is there for a good reason, and furthermore, your code shows an excellent example of why C-style casts are bad- because they can cast away const, and none of the other answerers noticed, whereas if you had been forced to use a `const_cast`, everybody would have noticed how bad that was.

However, should you take a valid `const MyType*`, then the cast will be redundant, and `&*iterator` is a perfectly good way to go about it.

Comment: Is a "mutable pointer or reference to an element in a vector" ok?  My set/vector/whatever contains objects that have collections themselves... and I'd like to add to those collections.

Comment: In a vector, yes it's OK. Basically, you should trust the compiler. Remove the cast; if the compiler lets you take a non-const pointer, then it's OK.

Comment: Feel free to answer the question, but using your answer as a platform for being rude about deficiencies in other people's answers seems a bit off. There is downvoting and comments if you wish to point out deficiencies in other answers.

Comment: @Tomalak: I was rude about the deficiencies of C-style casts. The fact that nobody else noticed it supported my argument. I wasn't rude about anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

two things,

1. `static_cast`
2. You should really check that the object exists in the set before grabbing the pointer.

As to the approach, if you fleshed out what you are trying to do, there could be a better way...

EDIT: oops, the `static_cast` is redundant too... habit, whenever I see a C-style cast...

Answer (score 1):

What you have is fine, although:

- You should probably check that the iterator is valid before dereferencing it.
- There is no need for the cast.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you know the element exists...

> Is this the best way to get a pointer to an instance of MyType in S?

No. You don't need the cast. And if you did, it shouldn't be a C cast, it should be a `const_cast`.